# Help! What's wrong with my succulent plant?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, leaves, diseases

**Hello,** I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my plant, or even find an image on the internet that resembles the issue. It appears my plant has bad skin. It looks sad, but it doesn't smell bad, and the leaves still feel perfectly firm and healthy to touch. It's in a terrarium, and the other 2 flowers in there are perfectly healthy. I've had this terrarium for almost 4 months now. I water it every 3 Mondays, and it gets a full day of natural sunlight 1-2x a week. I've shown it to a few people in my office and they have no idea what the issue is. Hoping maybe someone here might have a solution!
[image]

Comment: How much water do you use when you water?  This is very tiny and when watering you should be using a sprayer for the soil.  No drainage but this should work well unless you soak these plants, then you are watering too much.  The other issue is tap water with high salts.  We'll be back.  Great pictures btw.

Answer (score 1):

[succulent watering](https://www.succulentsandsunshine.com/how-to-water-succulent-plants/)

I am fairly sure this is too much water.  This article actually talks about spraying to water your terrarium.  Hope this helps.  Succulents, as you know, store their own water so once a month watering is normal.  But, if you soak these guys, they have to sit in saturated soil and then we've got compromised roots. The succulents will look as if they haven't been watered because the roots have rotted. Check this article out and give us feedback.  There will be other answers as well.

Comment: Thanks!! I just put a little bit of water in a straw and drop it directly in the middle of bowl when I water it. Not soaking it at all. I can definitely try spraying it instead though! I've read before that the leaves would feel soft or soggy if I've overwatered, but they're perfectly fine in that regard -- so I didn't know what to think. Thanks for the article! If I use the spray method, should I be spraying it more than once a month then? Article says daily, but not sure if that applies to my terrarium or not.

Comment: Try to not adhere to any schedule.  Daily?  Totally depends on how much one sprays.  Would you please stick your fingers into the soil and feel how wet/dry that soil is.  Do not water until that soil is dry.  So you are saying you use the straw and a 'straw full' of water once every three weeks?  That is too little!!  I was thinking you'd dump a coffee cup full of water in there and that would be too much.  Let us know...

Comment: Oh no! I must be under watering then?? I only use a straw yes, so spray until the soil feels damp then?

Comment: That could be the problem, Samantha.  Spray as if you were a light rain in the desert.  Any more than that you'd need drainage.  Move the gravel around a bit so you can see the soil.  Can you see the roots through the glass?  Are there brownish looking roots?  Or are they all white?  If you can, I would get a bottle of 'spring' water or distilled water from the grocery store.  Use that instead of tap water.